# List of "View Models" returns Null

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used List Instance of ViewModel to gather the data from the query and am trying to display in the View.However the object "CustomerVMlist" is return null with no results,customerlist is showing me 4 query results. and my view is completely empty.

```
public class CustomerVM
{

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Mobileno { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> OrderPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Index Function

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<CustomerVM> CustomerVMlist = new List<CustomerVM>(); // to hold list of Customer and order details

    var customerlist =(from Cust in db.Customers
                       join Ord in db.Orders 
                       on Cust.CustomerID equals Ord.CustomerID
                       select new 
                       { 
                           Cust.Name, 
                           Cust.Mobileno, 
                           Cust.Address, 
                           Ord.OrderDate, Ord.OrderPrice
                       }).ToList();

    foreach (var item in customerlist) 
    {
        CustomerVM VMOBJ = new CustomerVM();
        VMOBJ.Name= item.Name;
        VMOBJ.Mobileno = item.Mobileno;
        VMOBJ.Address = item.Address;
        VMOBJ.OrderDate = item.OrderDate;
        VMOBJ.OrderPrice = item.OrderPrice;
    }

    return View(CustomerVMlist);// returns null 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add items to the list

```
 foreach (var item in customerlist) {
    CustomerVM VMOBJ = new CustomerVM();
    VMOBJ.Name= item.Name;
    VMOBJ.Mobileno = item.Mobileno;
    VMOBJ.Address = item.Address;
    VMOBJ.OrderDate = item.OrderDate;
    VMOBJ.OrderPrice = item.OrderPrice;
    CustomerVMlist.Add(VMOBJ);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to add the objects you create in your list.

```
foreach (var item in customerlist) 
{
    CustomerVM VMOBJ = new CustomerVM();
    VMOBJ.Name= item.Name;
    VMOBJ.Mobileno = item.Mobileno;
    VMOBJ.Address = item.Address;
    VMOBJ.OrderDate = item.OrderDate;
    VMOBJ.OrderPrice = item.OrderPrice;

    // after having set all the values you add the newly created object to the list.
    CustomerVMlist.Add(VMOBJ);
}
```

You could achieve the same thing with fewer lines of code like below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var CustomerVMlist = (from Cust in db.Customers
                          join Ord in db.Orders 
                          on Cust.CustomerID equals Ord.CustomerID
                          select new CustomerVM
                          { 
                              Name = Cust.Name, 
                              Mobileno = Cust.Mobileno, 
                              Address = Cust.Address, 
                              OrderDate = Ord.OrderDate, 
                              OrderPrice = Ord.OrderPrice
                          }).ToList();

    return View(CustomerVMlist)
}
```

As you see we can project our result to the desired type, `CustomerVM`, without having to loop through the result set (with the `foreach`), create one by one the desired obejcts and adding them to the list.